# What's wrong with this question and answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-questions

This question

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/game-where-you-guess-which-cards-come-out-of-a-semi-shuffled-deck/29444?noredirect=1#comment39886_29444

Outlines a specific game mechanic, saying 'name this game'.

This is an open opportunity for anyone to say 'that sounds a bit like xyz game'.

Both my question and my answer both got lots of downvotes. What's actually wrong with it?

Curiously, it has received no close votes. Not off topic?

Comment: Your question seems to really be "I made up this game.  Does it already exist?"  It doesn't help that you then attempted to "answer" your own question with a nonsense answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is an abuse of the [identify-this-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) question type. That tag is intended for questions that are asking to identify a specific game that actually exists based on details that the asker can remember. This is made very clear in the tag description

> What is this game? (Include as many details as possible, **so we aren't left guessing**!)

And your answer does not really answer the question as the tags imply the question should be answered. Those answers are supposed to refer to a game that already existed; making up a game on the spot that just happens to match the description in the question is not a valid answer to an [identify-this-game](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bidentify-this-game%5d).

The only reason that your question doesn't have close votes is because (by my reading of the rules) it just barely skirts the line of being technically on topic. In a vacuum, the question is a completely valid identify-this-game question. On the other hand, based on what you wrote in your answer and this meta question, a good case could be made that what you are actually asking is a recommendation question, and since those are off topic, those votes are going to start coming in.